# Populating multi column combo-box, with sheet data, after selecting previous combo-box to determine data

Tags: vba, combobox

I have two combo-boxes, the first one you pick to select what shows in the second one. And what ever you pick in the first one, the second one should show two columns.

I had it running with one column in the second combo-box with

```
Private Sub cbo_area_Change()
    'Populate Equipment combo box.
    Dim strRange As String
    If cbo_area.ListIndex > -1 Then
       strRange = cbo_area
       Label2.Caption = strRange
       strRange = Replace(strRange, " ", "_")
            With cbo_asset
                .RowSource = vbNullString
                .RowSource = strRange
                .ListIndex = 0
            End With
    End If
End Sub
```

and now after much research and trying various things, I have tried the following to get two columns.

```
Private Sub cbo_area_Change()
    'Populate Equipment combo box.
    Dim strRange As String
    Dim strRange2 As String
    If cbo_area.ListIndex > -1 Then
       strRange = cbo_area
       Label2.Caption = strRange
       strRange = Replace(strRange, " ", "_")
       strRange2 = strRange & "2"
            With cbo_asset
                .RowSource = vbNullString
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = strRange
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = strRange2
                .ListIndex = 0
            End With
    End If
End Sub
```

But I get an `invalid property array index` at the `List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = strRange` line.

Like I said, I tried many things but I do not get further than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an item to the list before you assign a value to it.  The added item become column 0.

```
    With cbo_asset
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "60pt;75pt;"
        .RowSource = vbNullString
        .AddItem strRange
        .list(.ListCount - 1, 1) = strRange2
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
```

Comment: Thanks allot for coming back with this. I have tried it and it works, now I can use it for other things as well...